# AS3 case statement value access of undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a class that I made to control all my buttons from a centralized location. The buttons are pushed into an array on load and a for loop adds a MouseEvent.CLICK event listener to all the buttons in the array.

Now my problem comes in with the function tied to this event listener. I have created a switch statement

```
function btnclick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        switch (e.currentTarget)
        {
            case Profile_btn_63 :
                removearrayreference(this);
                e.currentTarget.parent.gotoAndStop("profile");
                break;

        }
    }
```

but the problem is when I test the game it states Profile_btn_63 is undefined. Which is actually true at the very beginning(first frame) as the button hasn't been added to the button array yet nor has an event listener been placed on it. So to get to the point I need help with making flash ignore that Profile_btn_63 is undefined until it eventually does get defined.

Finally this may be somewhat off topic but does anyone know why _63 is added to the end of Profile_btn when it is pushed into my button array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to have a "magic switch statement" that does everything in your program - which is a horrible idea in more than one way, but that is a different matter - then you should make the `case` decisions based on the instance name: `switch( e.currentTarget.name )`

While a button instance may be `null` or `undefined`, a constant String never is.

Comment: This switch statement doesn't do everything. I just made it so I can easily add new buttons with specialized functions instead of having to create a separate class for each and every button. But seeing as this project is supposed to be a learning experience and I want to get better at AS3 can you point me in a "better direction" or way of going about this?

Comment: Oh and the buttons now work perfectly with your help, but again if there is a better way of going about this then please by all means point me in the right direction.

Comment: If your goal is to really not create classes, then you've already achieved what you wanted.  If you want to learn how to keep your code clean and reusable, you have to kiss that idea goodbye and rather learn *why* you should create classes, and what should go in there.  To try to explain this would go wayyy too far. But if you really want to learn something, start reading up on object oriented programming first, then some basic design patterns http://www.as3dp.com/, and once you think you understand those, look into some of Uncle Bob Martin's videos http://cleancoders.com/